# How to draw transparent textures in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, transparency, lwjgl

I have been trying to draw a transparent texture in LWJGL. However, the code I have doesn't seem to work. Whenever I run the code, the transparent image appears but the background is completely black.

Here's what I mean by completely black, but the image is fine:

[image]

I have been able to draw non-transparent textures, but so far I've had no luck with drawing this one correctly.

I would like to know what is missing/incorrect in this code.

Code for drawing texture:

```
//draw transparent texture    
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_TEXTURE);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GL11.glPushMatrix();    

GL11.glColor4d(1,1,1,1);

texture.bind();

GL11.glTranslated(0.5,0.5,0.0);
GL11.glRotated(270-this.getAngle(),0.0,0.0,1.0);
GL11.glTranslated(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);

GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
{
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    GL11.glVertex2d(this.getX(), this.getY());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    GL11.glVertex2d(this.getX(),(this.getY()+this.getHeight()));
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    GL11.glVertex2d((this.getX()+this.getWidth()),(this.getY()+this.getHeight()));
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    GL11.glVertex2d((this.getX()+this.getWidth()), this.getY());
}
GL11.glEnd();

GL11.glPopMatrix();
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Here's the code that loads the texture from the file:

```
private Texture loadTexture(String key){
    try {
        //in this case, key refers to a valid power of 2, transparent png
        return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/"+key+".png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that loads the texture from file and uploads it to OpenGL? Does your image contains alpha?

Comment: OK, I had a suspicion that it might be important, but I'm also unsure about it.

Comment: What does `texture.getFormat()` return?

Comment: Also, try `glBlendFunc(GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA); glBlendColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5);` just for grins and see if it draws it half transparent. If it does, it's a texture format issue. If it doesn't, it's something else.

Comment: It seems ok. Your image must have the problem. Add this please before `TextureLoader.getTexture()` and see what it prints: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/"+key+".png"));     System.out.println( img.getColorModel().hasAlpha() );`

Comment: It prints "true". So I assume the image is OK.

Comment: Did you check the alpha values of your non-transparent image?

Comment: If it prints `true` then your image has an alpha channel and should be ok. Are you clearing the color buffer to a black color? (Please post the whole code that draws your scene otherwise we will keep guessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code does not seem to have a problem. By using the simple code from the [Slick-Util Library - Part 1 - Loading Images for LWJGL](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_1_-_Loading_Images_for_LWJGL.html) and replacing the `render()` method with your code I was able to correctly see transparency using this RGBA image of an up arrow:

[image: Up arrow image]

Please make sure that you are clearing your colorbuffer in a color other than black i.e. use

```
GL11.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);  // try with red (1, 0, 0, 1) green (0, 1, 0, 1) to check the image's transparent area.
```

If this doesn't work for your case, please post a full runnable example because the problem must lie in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 4):

you just need to add this:

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

in your init function :)

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.